# Button to toggle text field, true and false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form to create a true/false question. I am trying to have a button to toggle the value of a text_field from true and false. (I really do not care what way it is done, I just want the user to be able to easily change the answer to true or false.

This is what I have, it only toggles one time to false and only works when I click the text field not the button. I am trying to learn javascript, so bear with me...

```
<%= f.label :content, "Answer" %>
<%= f.text_field :content, :value => 'True', :readonly => true, :class => "d-id", :id => "answer" %>
<%= button_tag "Toggle True/False", :id => "answer", :class => "btn btn-small btn-inverse", :type => "button" %>


<script>
function checkAnswer() {
if ($("#answer").val('False'))
    {
    $("#answer").val('True');
    }
    if ($("#answer").val('True'))
    {
    $("#answer").val('False');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#answer').click(function () {
    checkAnswer();
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/ene5w/

I cleaned up your syntax some and came up with this -

```
function checkAnswer() {
    var answer = $('#answer').val();
    if ('False' == answer) {
        $("#answer").val('True');
    } else {
        $("#answer").val('False');
    }
}
```

Also, you have **two elements with the same ID which is not allowed in an HTML page**. You'll get wonky results. You could change these to classes.

Changed to a button instead of a link - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/ene5w/1/

Change the text of the button - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/ene5w/2/

Comment: Works great, +1 for the HTML assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($("#answer").val() === 'False') {
    $("#answer").val('True');
 } else {
    $("#answer").val('False');
}
```

Comment: So this works, but only when clicking the text_field. Do you know how to get the button to work?

Comment: Changed the `#answer` with button `id`, I noticed that you have set same `id` for `button` and `text` `input`, use `class` name or change the `id`